# Java.Net.ProtocolException: 'Unexpected status line: <html>' on consecutive api call through httpclient

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I Have a view which lists reservations associated with currently logged in user. Once user clicks on one of those reservations, he navigates to details view which connects to api through httpclient and gets reservation details. The code is listed below.

```
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.TokenStr);

                var result = await client.GetAsync($"/api/reservation/getforid?Id={id}");
                client.Dispose();
                if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var str = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\\", " ");
                    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReservationModel>(str);

                    return model;
                }
```

The details page also allows for modyfing certain data of selected reservation and upon successful editing, the view is closed and the reservation data is to be reloaded again.

What happens though is Java.Net.ProtocolException is thrown on client.getAsync(). And while requests to api is made, it seems that the httpclient doesnt await for the data, but gets some false response which is unable to be translated to response object.

To sum up:

1. The HttpClient connects to api without any problem when the first request to show reservation detail page is made.
2. After modyfing reservation, and trying to reload reservation data, the exception is thrown, even though the code/data making the request is same

EDIT:

I refactored my project so that it uses shared HttpClient instance and found the line of code which is causing the problem.

```
   private IMvxCommand submit;
        public IMvxCommand Submit
        {
            get
            {
                submit = submit ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
                {
                    var validationResult =  validateFields();
                    if (validationResult)
                    {
                        await _personApi.UpdatePerson(Model);
                        _nav.Close(this,true);
                 
                    }
                });
                return submit;
            }
        }
```

the _personApi.UpdatePerson() method seems to be somehow messing stuff up.
After commenting it the view closes, and ReservationDetailsView which lists persons successfully fetches data. However when i uncomment that method, upon navigating to ReservationDetailViewModel the same exception gets thrown...

you can see the UpdatePerson method below:

```
  public async Task UpdatePerson(PersonModel model)
        {

            var token = GetCurrentToken();

            //client = new HttpClient();
            //   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.TokenStr);
            //  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type","application/json");
            var dynamic = new { model.Id, model.Name, model.NumberPhone, model.Pesel, model.Street, model.Email, model.WhoToInfrom, model.PostalCode, model.CityPerson };
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamic), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var result = await client.PostAsync($"/api/person/update", content);


        }
```

EDIT 2:

Still stuck on the problem, doesn't matter how many times i'll use the HttpClient it works fine until i make HttpClient call from PersonApi in EditPersonViewModel which updates person.

Any subsequent call will actually connect to my API (i have breakpoints set in, no exceptions are thrown) but the client receives response as below. Where is it coming from?

[image]

This the error which IIS logs:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 30.07.2021 11:14:01 
Event time (UTC): 30.07.2021 09:14:01 
Event ID: 17452691323540639122452734bf1713 
Event sequence: 19 
Event occurrence: 15 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/62/ROOT-4-132720999030559530 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\www\abc\AbcHoliday\AbcHoliday\ 
    Machine name: SERVER3 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 11392 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\abc.syntio.pl 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: TaskCanceledException 
    Exception message: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://abc.syntio.pl/api/reservation/getforid?Id=6384 
    Request path: /api/reservation/getforid 
    User host address: 10.10.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: JWT 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\abc.syntio.pl 
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 25 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\abc.syntio.pl 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: have you checked the server logs, or tested with Postman or a browser?  There are numerous existing questions about "unexpected status line" and they seem to point to a problem on the server

Comment: Have you considered declaring Submit as an `IMvxAsyncCommand` instead of `IMvxCommand` ? I don't think this is part of the problem, but it's a better practice, especially since you are already using async/await inside the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want a try/catch around Web API calls in the VM. You can't expect this call to succeed every single time! You can fall back on a cached response on error.

Based on the error description, it sounds like you are not able to parse the JSON correctly. You may need to provide custom `JsonSerializerSettings` compatible with the settings your API server is using. Newtonsoft should be throwing a `JsonSerializationException` with more information if the problem is due to JSON serialization/deserialization errors.

As for the Java Exceptions, Xamarin.Android by default uses `AndroidClientHandler` these days. There appears to be some bugs because you can catch Java exceptions (exceptions thrown from the Java.Lang.* namespace) in your .NET Standard/PCL project. That's a bad situation because the .NET Standard/PCL project doesn't know about Android.

I recommend using the following approach in a modern Xamarin.Android app using MvvmCross:

1. Use a single instance of HttpClient across the application. Normally the best way to do that would be to use `IHttpClientFactory`, but Xamarin doesn't have great support for that (yet). A good place to instantiate the HttpClient is inside your `MvxAndroidSetup`.

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup<App>
{
  protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
  {
    base.InitializeFirstChance();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new BasicAuthenticationDelegatingHandler(new SafeAndroidClientHandler()));

    // TODO: Setup httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders, etc.

    Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton(httpClient);
  }
}
```

2. Use a `SafeAndroidClientHandler` to catch the Java.Lang.* exceptions being thrown by HttpClient and rethrow then wrapped in a .NET-friendly Exception. Here is my implementation. You would do something similar for the `GetAsync` method override.

```cs
public class SafeAndroidClientHandler : AndroidClientHandler
{
    public SafeAndroidClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Now you can simply inject `HttpClient` into ViewModels, Services, etc. thanks to MvvmCross IoC. If a Java.Lang.* exception is thrown it would now be caught as a `HttpRequestException` in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) says:

> // HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Given that:

- Don't call `client.Dispose;`
- Don't create an HTTPClient on each call - create it once.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i wasnt aware of that. Any idea of where i should store such HttpClient instance? or just any plain wrapping class will do?

Comment: @KamilBrucki - it doesn't matter. In a simple app, I collect statics either in my custom App (or Application) subclass, or in a stand-alone static class. In a bigger project, I would make a folder that holds all classes related to HTTP or related to communication with server. A static class in that same folder would be good.

Comment: You're using MvvmCross, so store the `HttpClient` in the IoC container as a singleton from the Android project inside the method MvxAndroidSetup.InitializeFirstChance().